# Matlab's Integral won't work while integral2 will

Tags: matlab

I get an error everytime I use Matlab's "Integral" function. I can cheat the system and use integral2 to do the same job, but some of my old code is using integral (and it is also silly to do anyway).

Here's what I get every single time:

> integral(@(z) z.^2, 0,1)
>
> Error: File: integralCalc.m Line: 1 Column: 2
>
> Function definitions are not permitted in this context.
>
> Error in integral (line 88)
>   Q = integralCalc(fun,a,b,opstruct);
>
> integral2(@(z,t) z.^2, 0 ,1,0,1)
>
> ans =
>
> 0.3333

Comment: What MATLAB version are you on? `integral(@(z)z.^2,0,1)` works for me on MATLAB R2016a.

Comment: That's the thing!, it worked for me before... :( Release: R2015b Product: MATLAB Product Version: 8.6 Platform: Maci64 Operating System: Maci64 Any